# How to Test Exception in Flutter Bloc Test

Tags: flutter, testing, mockito, bloc

I'm trying to write BLoC tests using the bloc_test framework in Flutter. Before anyone tries taking this down, no this isn't the same as testing for exceptions in a widget/unit test for Flutter. BLoC tests are different.

I have a cubit that I'm testing. It has a method called getPrinterForms(). I'm trying to test the exception being caught, to make sure it emits the correct states. Can anyone look at the code for my test, and the code for the method, and let me know if there's anything I'm doing wrong?

```
@GenerateMocks([PrinterRepositoryImpl])
void main() {
  late MockPrinterRepositoryImpl mockPrinterRepository;
  late PrinterCubit printerCubit;

  setUp(() {
    mockPrinterRepository = MockPrinterRepositoryImpl();
    printerCubit = PrinterCubit(mockPrinterRepository);
  });

  tearDown(() {
    printerCubit.close();
  });

  group('PrinterCubit Tests', () {
        blocTest(
      'getPrinterForms emits [PrinterLoading, PrinterError] when unsuccessful',
      build: () {
        when(mockPrinterRepository.fetchPrinterForms(http.Client())).thenThrow(NetworkException());
        return printerCubit;
      },
      act: (PrinterCubit cubit) => cubit.getPrinterForms(),
      expect: () => [
        PrinterLoading(),
        const PrinterError("Couldn't fetch printer forms. Is the device online?")
      ],
    );
  });
}



class NetworkException implements Exception{}
```

```
  Future<void> getPrinterForms() async {
    try {
      emit(PrinterLoading());
      final printerForms = await _printerRepository.fetchPrinterForms(http.Client());
      emit(PrinterLoaded(printerForms));
    } on NetworkException {
      emit(const PrinterError("Couldn't fetch printer forms. Is the device online?"));
    }    
  }
```

```
@override
abstract class PrinterState extends Equatable {
  const PrinterState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class PrinterInitial extends PrinterState {}

class PrinterLoading extends PrinterState {}

class PrinterLoaded extends PrinterState {
  final List<PrinterModel> printerForms;
  const PrinterLoaded(this.printerForms);
}

class PrinterDetails extends PrinterState {
  final PrinterModel printerForm;
  const PrinterDetails(this.printerForm);
}

class PrinterError extends PrinterState {
  final String message;
  const PrinterError(this.message);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you add the test result? Also the whole code of the cubit would help, as well as the declaration of the states it can emit.

Comment: I edited the question to add that now.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and I cannot reproduce a failed test.

```dart
@GenerateMocks([PrinterRepository])
void main() {
  late PrinterRepository mockPrinterRepository;

  setUp(() {
    mockPrinterRepository = MockPrinterRepository();
  });

  group('PrinterCubit Tests', () {
    blocTest(
      'emits [PrinterLoading, PrinterError] when unsuccessful',
      build: () {
        when(mockPrinterRepository.fetchPrinterForms())
            .thenThrow(NetworkException());
        return PrinterCubit(mockPrinterRepository);
      },
      act: (PrinterCubit cubit) => cubit.getPrinterForms(),
      expect: () => [
        PrinterLoading(),
        const PrinterError(
          "Couldn't fetch printer forms. Is the device online?",
        )
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

The cubit looks like this:

```dart
class PrinterCubit extends Cubit<PrinterState> {
  PrinterCubit([PrinterRepository? printerRepository]) : super(PrinterInitial()) {
    _printerRepository = printerRepository ?? PrinterRepository();
  }

  late PrinterRepository _printerRepository;

  Future<void> getPrinterForms() async {
    try {
      emit(PrinterLoading());
      final printerForms = await _printerRepository.fetchPrinterForms();
      emit(PrinterLoaded(printerForms));
    } on NetworkException {
      emit(const PrinterError(
        "Couldn't fetch printer forms. Is the device online?",
      ));
    }
  }
}

class NetworkException implements Exception {}

class PrinterRepository {
  Future<List<PrinterModel>> fetchPrinterForms() async {
    return [PrinterModel("Samsung"), PrinterModel("HP")];
  }
}

class PrinterModel {
  PrinterModel(this.name);

  final String name;
}
```

```sh
00:01 +1: All tests passed!
```

Comment: Hmm.....interesting. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: How does your test fail?

Comment: So, I modified the code since yesterday (nothing major, just added an http.Client parameter to the fetchPrinterForms() method for other test purposes, I updated my post to include the changes in the code). I'm getting an error saying "MissingStubError: 'fetchPrinterForms'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
fetchPrinterForms(Instance of 'IOClient')". I tried added http.Client to the GenerateMocks annotation to fix this, and put a mockClient in the parameter, to see if that was the problem, but it's not.

Comment: Aha! Fixed it! I simply put the 'any' keyword inside the method call, instead of http.Client().

Comment: Glad, you figured it out.